# Find which formula column is used in the column

Tags: microsoft-excel

this excel column D1,D2,D3, is calculate from column A,B,C.
There formula are D1= A2+B2,D2= B2+C2,D3 =C2-B2.

Excel:
[image: EXCEL]

Assume today I want to find which formula column is used in the column C, in other words is I want to know formula of D2 and D3 are contains the column C.

Is there a way to find it by excel?

Comment: If I correctly understand may be FIND or SEARCH function with FORMULATEXT function might help here.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your objective, since you already know that it is columns "D2" and "D3" that reference C in their formula. If you want to be able to determine this using a formula in another cell, placing `=FORMULATEXT(E2)` in cell G2, then G2 will contain `=B2+C2`.  Thus you can just test to see if there is a "C" in cell G2. Also, I cannot emphasize strongly enough that you do not want user-named column headings of D1, D2, and D3.  You will be *certain* to eventually use D1, D2 or D3 in a formula accidentally.   A reference to D3 will return excel cell D3, not your column D3.

Comment: beacause I have many formula column ,so I want to can fast to find the general cell.

Comment: How do you want to display the cell? Highlight the cell? Or other ways? In Excel you can use the "Trace Precedents" and "Trace Dependents" feature: https://www.educba.com/auditing-tools-in-excel/